# Deriving Fourier Transform of Time-Windowed Discrete Signal

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, dtft

I'm trying to derive the Fourier Transform of a finite-length discrete signal to show the effect of windowing,e.g. spectral leakage and resolution, but I can't seem to arrive at the same answer.

Just some notation: normal braces, (), indicate the CT signal and square brackets, [], indicate the DT signal.

A continuous-time (CT) signal, $x(t)$, is sampled with sampling period, $T_s$, to give:
$$
x_s(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}x\left[nT_s\right]\delta\left(t-nT_s\right)
$$
and is then time-windowed with a tophat function, $h(t)$, of width $L$:
\begin{align}
x_L(t) &= x_s(t)\cdot h(t) \\
&= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}x\left[nT_s\right]h\left[n\right]\delta\left(t-nT_s\right) \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x\left[nT_s\right]h\left[n\right]\delta\left(t-nT_s\right)
\end{align}
where $L = NT_s$. The corresponding Fourier Transforms are:
\begin{align}
X_s\left(e^{j\omega}\right)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x_s(t)e^{-j\omega t} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}x\left[nT_s\right]\delta\left(t-nT_s\right)e^{-j\omega t} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}x\left[nT_s\right]e^{-jwnT_s} \\
X_L\left(e^{j\omega}\right)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x_L(t)e^{-j\omega t} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}x\left[nT_s\right]h\left[n\right]\delta\left(t-nT_s\right)e^{-j\omega t} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x\left[nT_s\right]e^{-jwnT_s} \\
\end{align}
I think the last equation above is the DTFT of $x_L(t)$ and is what I'm trying to achieve. Now I choose to write the time-windowing in terms of a convolution in the frequency domain:
\begin{align}
X_L\left(e^{j\omega}\right)&=\mathcal{F}\left\lbrace x_s\cdot h(t)\right\rbrace \\
&=X_s\left(e^{j\omega}\right)*H\left(j\omega\right) \\
&=\left(\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}x\left[nT_s\right]e^{-jwnT_s}\right) * H\left(j\omega\right) \\
\end{align}
I can't see how the infinite summation reduces to a finite summation over $N$ samples without $h(t)$. The transform $H\left(j\omega\right)$ is a $\mathrm{sinc}$ function so I'm not sure how to proceed to get the same result as above.